# Extract contents from Scene

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to extract the contents from a scene and put in a pane. The problem is that nothing appears in the pane if I get the root component from the scene and add it to the pane.

Note: the scene is not added to a stage or to any other component.

The following is my (messy, for now) code:

> public class JanelaPrincipalController extends Controller implements
>   Initializable {
>
> ```
> @FXML
> private ResourceBundle resources;
>
> @FXML
> private URL location;
>
> @FXML
> private StackPane conteudo;
>
> @FXML
> private MenuItem miBolsas;
>
> @FXML
> private MenuItem miCorretoras;
>
> /**
>  * Initializes the controller class.
>  */
> @Override
> public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
>     miBolsas.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
>         @Override
>         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
>             System.out.println("Action performed");
>             conteudo.getChildren().clear();
>             SceneData sceneData = MainClass.getInstance().getScene(SceneType.LISTA_BOLSAS);
>             Parent root = sceneData.scene().getRoot();
>             conteudo.getChildren().add(root);
>             //conteudo.getChildren().add(new Label("Teste"));
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> @Override
> public void open() {
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
> }
>
> @Override
> public void process(Action action) {
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
> }
>
> @Override
> public void close() {
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Do you get a runtime error? I would expect something along the lines of "this node is already part of a scene graph".

Comment: @ceklock scene and stackpane both are in same file ? or its on different controller file ?

Comment: please post a short, self contained correct example for this and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @James_D: I don't get any error. I just don't see the expected content inside the pane, it is empty. I am refactoring my code, the content was displayed normally inside a stage.

Comment: @AnshulParashar: scene is in different file.

Comment: I think you probably need to remove the root from the scene it's in before you add it as a child to your StackPane. I would expect an exception to be thrown here: are you squashing exceptions at the point where you load the associated FXML?

Comment: No exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the scene. The root node was added to a Scene, so it can't be displayed in other place. Have to remove the node from the Scene.

I am refactoring the code, I just don't need to add some contents directly to scenes now.

I was using this method in my MainClass:

```
public static SceneData loadSceneFromFXML(final String fxmlFile, final Controller controller) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainClass.class.getResource(fxmlFile));
    if (controller != null) {
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
    }
    Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
    return new SceneData(scene, controller);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same Node (in this case the Parent), con not be shown twise, therefore, if your scene was being shown, you will need to remove the root from the scene, and then you add it to stackpane.

Comment: I found the problem, it was more or less that... the root node was added to a Scene. Doesn't matter if the scene is shown or not. If the node is linked to a scene, it can't be displayed in other place.